# Angular2 window resize event does not have target value

Tags: angular

Angular2 : I'm using one the solution for handling window resize event. But I'm not getting the event.target value to fetch width of the window.

```
(window:resize)="onResize($event)"

onResize(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.target);
}
```

Log...

```
{"isTrusted":true}
undefined
```

How to fetch the width on window:resize event?

Comment: Strange, ideally it should work. Have you tried `event.currentTarget`?

Comment: Yes. Looks strange to me. This is the only value I'm getting {"isTrusted":true}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little example work for me:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <h1 (window:resize)="onResize($event)">{{title}}</h1>
        `
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Hello window object !';

      onResize(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log("width:" + event.target.innerWidth);
        console.log("height:" + event.target.innerHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/95R1RAT43wW1KV2DHaQh?p=preview)

Comment: Which is the best way to implement this? capturing window event or using ngZone? any thoughts.

Comment: You mix two different things, Zone is is an execution context that persists across async tasks and Angular2 use zone for a smart detection of a modification of the model. In your case, you need just to implement a event on the window.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
constructor(ngZone:NgZone) {
    super();
    window.onresize = (e) =>
       {
           ngZone.run(() => {
                this.callMethod(window.innerWidth);
           });
       };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't required any target value as you are calling window resize event. You can get window dimensions as below as well:

**Call Event:**

```
(window:resize)="onResize($event)"
```

**Event:**

```
onResize(event) {
   console.log(window.innerWidth);
   console.log(window.innerHeight);
}
```